# How to generate image file with C++ gnuplot?

Tags: c++, graph, gnuplot, data-visualization

I am trying to implement Gnuplot on C++ to create a heat map. Once I run the following code, it opens a new gnu plot window with the plot on it. Can't I just write the graph as image file instead opening it on new window ?

Code:

```
Gnuplot gp;
gp << "unset key\n";
gp << "set pm3d\n";
// gp << "set hidden3d\n";
gp << "set view map\n";
gp << "set xrange [ 0 : 10 ] \n";
gp << "set yrange [ 0 : 10 ] \n";
gp << "splot '-'\n";
gp.send2d(frame);
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.math.utk.edu/~vasili/refs/How-to/gnuplot.print.html

Answer (score 1):

Just add output. Below code should work for you:

```
Gnuplot gp;
gp << "unset key\n";
gp << "set pm3d\n";
// gp << "set hidden3d\n";
gp << "set view map\n";
gp << "set xrange [ 0 : 10 ] \n";
gp << "set yrange [ 0 : 10 ] \n";
gp << "set terminal png \n";
gp << "set output 'b.png' \n";
gp << "splot '-'\n";
gp.send2d(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your script :

```
gp << "set terminal png\n";
gp << "set output 'my_file.png'\n";
```

There are other formats available, you can see [this page](http://www.gnuplotting.org/output-terminals/) to get more informations.